# How would I access a back-end webpage?

Tags: html, url, path

These files I have uploaded to my host provider "hostinger". Now usually the `index.html` page would be the root page of the webpage itself by accessing it like `SOMEPAGE.com`. Also I have an `admin.html` file which is some sort of a settings page where want to be able to make changes into and access `index.html` page.
How would I be able to access that page the same way I would access the `index.html` or `SOMEPAGE.com` in the web in the link bar of the browser?

[image]

Comment: https://example.com/admin.html

Comment: Will thank you very much for the Help ...god bless you my friend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL can accept a path to a directory structure on your server starting at the web root, which in your case is the directory where `index.html` is stored. By default if the file name is omitted the web server will look for a file called `index.html` and try to display that in the browser. If you specify a different file name it will look for that file instead.

In your case to access `admin.html` you only need to specify the file name after the domain.

```
example.com/admin.html
```

If it was in another folder you can specify the folder path separate by `/`

```
example.com/somefolder/admin.html
```

Comment: Aha! so even if the file is located inside a folder then you have to specify the folder name in the link bar. Thank you so much for the advice Dharman.